# How to define dbhandler constructor variables in mainactivity?

Tags: android, sqlite

dbhandler class

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "feedbackDB.db";
private static final String TABLE_FEEDBACK = "feedback";
private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.vbfeed/databases/";

public DBHandler(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context,context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
```

Main activity code under `onCreate` and button on Click

```
DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(getBaseContext(),name,null, 1);
//having error in this line--just constructor defining error,
//i dono the variables to declare
```

Comment: Change your constructor to

 

    `public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }` and use `DBHandler db = new DBHnadler(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your constructor to

```
  public DBHandler(Context context) { 
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
```

and use

```
  DBHandler db = new DBHnadler(this);
```

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Check the above links for reference.